# Visual Studio creates a template code that does not work

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I have Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2022 Community on this comp. I have .NET 7  installed.
I want to create a template ASP.NET application.
I run the  Visual Studio and go to File→Add → Add project. I select “ASP.NET Core Web application”; then click Next:

[image]

The result is the following: Studio really creates the files, but they do not work; I just cannot open the project. For example, here is code of generated *.csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Any ideas about the problem?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: When I open the SLN file, no message at all.
When I open the *csproj  file I got the following error:


“Cannot file specified package” SDK “Microsoft.net.SDK.Web”

Comment: The project template is correct. It seems that your SDK is corrupted or something like this. Try repairing your visual studio, which will reinstall all packages.

Comment: “ Try repairing your visual studio ” unfortunately I have not found “Repair” button. So in the visual installer I have changed a couple of checked items and run the   installer. Then I tried – no, the problem still exists.

Any suggestions ?

BTW : here are folder I see in folder c:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\:

    6.0.22

    7.0.10

    7.0.11

May be it a root cause o f the problem?

Comment: See if you can create and run that exact template using dotnet CLI.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But could you please give more details about "exact template using dotnet CLI"; how would this like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does seem like the SDK or something similar is corrupted, you can fix it with Visual Studio by:

Open Visual Studio Installer => Find the Visual Studio you are using => More => Repair

[image]

If it still doesn't work, you can try reinstalling Visual Studio.

Finally, if this error still occurs after reinstalling Visual Studio, please open cmd and enter `dotnet --info`

**Update:**

I kind of know where this is going.

Cause Analysis:

Your system should have both x86 and x64 dotnet sdk installed, respectively.
C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet and C:\Program Files\dotnet directories. When using the dotnet command, the default is the x86 directory, causing the problem that the sdks cannot be found.

You can modify the environment variables and find the path
"This PC -> Right click 'Properties' -> Advanced system settings -> Environment Variables –> System variables –> double click path". Delete "C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet" and make sure there is "C:\Program Files\dotnet".

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: As for the Repair, it just does not exist in the drop-down menu More on my Studio instance.

You suggested “If it still doesn't work, you can try reinstalling Visual Studio “. I have run the “dotnet --info ”. Here is the result (WARNING: I have to cut out most of the info  - otherwise slowoverflow does allow to put such huge comment).

C:\Users\User>dotnet --info

Host:
  Version:      7.0.11
  Architecture: x86
  Commit:       ecb34f85ec

.NET SDKs installed:
  No SDKs were found.
....


May the "No SDKs were found" be root cause of the problem?

Comment: @VictorSotnikov You can edit the screenshots of your Visual Studio Installer without the repair option and the screenshots of you after executing "dotnet --info" into your post.